# Windows Explorer view options for individual folders

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I have one folder whose view options I would like to set for "Large Icons". For another folder, I want to set its view options for "Details". Unfortunately, it seems I can only set it globally. Is there a way to set view options for individual folders?

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 these get saved by default, but under one important condition.

You need a clean BagMRU in HKCR for that. Google on how to clean it. And that also needs to be small/clean, which implies the more folders you browse through time, the bigger it gets and the closer you get to explorer ignoring the BagsMRU settings. Once BagsMRU have been cleared, explorer will default all folder to a default setting. From there on, each time you set up a particular folder, it will remember those settings for that folder only by creating a BagMRU entry. Parents and child folders views will vary.

(For music folder, I've set up bit rate and duration instead of artists etc, it worked for a month or so, now it reverted to default music folder details view because I often have to create new folders and browse them, which lead to this limitation of explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Find the Tools menu at the top of your Explorer window. Then Tools > Folder Options >
View tab > Advanced Settings list > check the box next to "Remember each folder's view settings".

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not seeing this option. Instead, at the very top of the "View" tab, there is "Apply to Folders" options. I did a workaround, by selecting the folder's properties > Customize tab. Optimize this folder for: "Pictures". This defaults to large icons.

Answer (score 0):

"Remember each folder's view settings" has been removed in Windows 7. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7

Comment: As an options, now it remembers them by default.